# Whats the right way to make a navbar?

Tags: html, css

I recently just started learning HTML and CSS, and I was wondering if there was a very reliable and popular way to make a navbar. I've been watching a lot of tutorials, and everyone seems to do them very differently. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your needs, and what you're using. For instance, most CSS frameworks have specific ways to make structure navbars, and if you're using a JavaScript framework (like Vue) there might be external modules you can use to structure the page (like Vuetify). However, for HTML only you can use the `nav` tag although it's not required to do so. You could also simply use a `div` as the container for the navbar. Navbars are part of the site's design, so they should be adapted to fit it's theme, and thus designs vary from site to site. Use what works for you.

Comment: Also you can use bootstrap or zurb foundation, etc. as they provide these features built in

Comment: If you want to LEARN please do not use bootstrap or any of those, just don't. I would suggest that you take a look at this post on css-tricks and go from there https://css-tricks.com/where-do-you-learn-html-css-in-2020/ . Regarding navbars I think it depends on the design, how it should look like in smaller screens and larger screens. Learn some basics, `display: flex;`  is your friend when it comes to navbars (or html in general)

Comment: Voting to close as this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that there are many ways to do it - the easiest way would be to use a simple frontend framework like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/) and choose from the [Navbar Component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/) selection.

A navbar might seem like a simple thing, but to make a modern navbar that is easy to navigate for both web AND mobile platforms, and responsive, takes a decent amount of CSS styling. Easiest way to implement responsive design (in my opinion) from "scratch" is with Flexbox - best way to learn is with [Flexbox Froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/).

Additionally, for things like dropdown/expansion of the menu, javascript most likely could be required depending on the function you need. Of course, in the end it comes down to both function and design preference. A simple starting point to get the basic idea of this is through [W3 Schools' Popup Menu Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp) - this is not the best source to learn, but it's ok for a quick and dirty idea of some of what may be required.